# Deep Learning: How does the training process in PyTorch work?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

[image: my understanding]

This picture shows my understanding of the process of running a model and my question about the process of training a model.
Can anyone explain what happens then?

Thanks to @Michael Hearn 's answer, I grabbed information and filled the picture:
[image: complete]

Comment: @null This link gives me 404, so what do you mean?

Comment: sorry, updated link -> https://medium.com/p/796793789248

Comment: Ya this is a great diagram! If you give us some input on what you are trying to do we can give you some more direction, seems like you have a great grasp so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully someone says a better answer after mine later... So basically you are asking how a neural network functions. So the model is trained on the training data going in it then passes through nodes which run functions on the information and change it as it passes through. Then an output is generated. The output is compared to the test answer. Then through the not magical process of backpropagation the network is corrected. Nodes that were heavily responsible for giving wrong answers on the training set are changed so the next pass through they will be more likely to give the right answer.

[Backpropagation with PyTorch](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/notes-on-deep-learning-back-propagation-and-pytorch-21693552b733)

Comment: In fact I know nothing about deep learning, and I am just turning an implementation of a paper into a module with api, so I want more thing about "how to code this in PyTorch". Anyway, your answer describes the process clearly and helps me to grab information about it more easily, so huge thanks.